# VueJS Show element on child component one at a time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have several components `<server-header>`. It has the following HTML:

```
<span @click="$parent.changeOrder(column, $event)">
    <slot></slot>
    <i v-show="sortActive" class="order-arrow" :class="sort"></i>
</span>
```

These components are inserted in another component `<server-list>`. These will be the headers, that when clicked, will order some lists. My objective is to only show one arrow icon at a time.

E.g.: If I click on the first header, the arrow appears on that one. If I click on the second header, the arrow from the first header hides and the one on the second header appears.

This would be simple to do with jQuery for example, but I'm kind of lost on how to do this with VueJS.

Comment: inside `<server-list>` component, create one data property=`selected`, then pass `selected == index` to the props=`sort-active` of the component=`<server-header>` like `<template v-for="(item, index) in serverlist"><server-header sort-active="selected == index"></server-header></template>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call parent functions directly. That is an anti pattern. Instead use 2-way data binding with `sync` and this is much easier. Rough example below:

```
// server-list.vue
data() {
  return {
     selected: undefined
  }
}

<server-header v-for="(header, idx) in headers" :header="header" :selected.sync="selected" :idx="idx"></server-header
```

Then in the child, we drop `@click="$parent.changeOrder(column, $event)"` in favor of:

```
@click="$emit('update:selected', idx)"
```

Make sure `server-header` has this prop expected:

```
props: ['idx', 'header', 'selected']
```

Then make sure we compare the `idx` to our `header` index:

```
<i v-show="selected === index"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're rendering the `<server-header>` components with a `v-for` directive, looping a `server_headers` property in your `<server-list>` component `data` property.

The way i go with this is adding a prop to the `<server-header>` component like `selected`, then I add a `selected` property to each of the `server_headers` objects. Then i render the icon (`<i>`) with v-show if the correspondent `selected` property is true.

Like this:

`server-list component`

```
Vue.component('server-list', {
    data: () => ({
        server_headers: [{key: value, selected: true}, {key:value, selected:false}]
    }),
    template: `
      <div> 
           <server-header v-for="header of server_headers" :v-key="somekey" :selected="header.selected"></server_header>
      </div>
`
}

Vue.component('server-header', {
     props: ['selected'],
     template: `
         <span @click="$parent.changeOrder(column, $event)">
             <slot></slot>
             <i v-show="selected" class="order-arrow" :class="sort"></i>
         </span>
     `
})
```

Then, if i click on the arrow I would unset all the `selected` properties, and set the one i clicked. I hope this helps!!!!